# Read from text file and put into multi-2d array

Tags: c, matrix

How would I read string from a file and put it into a 2d array table. 
text file:

```
0 0/0a 1/0b 2/0c 3/0d 4/0e 5/99
1 0/0b 1/0b 2/99 4/0c 5/99
```

So, 0 is a first row,
0/0a means (0) is first column and (0a) is inserted in (0,0)

So, 1 is a second row. 
4/0c means (4) is fourth column and (0c) is inserted in (1, 4)

99 means 00, and should be replace with 00.
And if the column is missing (for example second row, there is no 3rd column, should be placed as 00).

expecting output:

```
  0  1  2  3  4  5
0 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 00
1 0b 0b 00 00 0c 00
```

Code I have done so far:

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(fp==NULL) return 1;
    printf("File is open successfully.\n");
    char *ptr, buf[256];
    while((ptr = fgets(buf, 256, fp)) != NULL){
        printf("%s", ptr);
    }
    fseek ( fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
}
```

I am just kind of lost, where to start. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Now do some operation on `buf`. Btw why are you printing `ptr`?

Comment: How do you know the number of columns ? It is fixed and equals to 5 ? Or is the input in fixed size fields with eventual trailing blanks ?

Comment: @1336087, to print out the text file, just to be sure. Mind giving me some example on buf?

Comment: your printf will give File is open successfuly always :)

Comment: @user4142604: is the column number fixed?

Comment: @Inquisitive, I edited it, please check op, just assume that 5 is a max column.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, I edited it, please check op, 5 is a max column according to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of columns may be less than 6 (0 to 5), then you should use `strtok` to split the line, get the line number with a simple `"%d"`, eventually print empty lines if the line number skips forward (it is an error if it skips backwards).

Then you step the columns reading them with `"%d/%x"`, set eventually skipped columns to 0, set the column to 0 if it is 0x99 (read as hexa ...).

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 6

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp;
    int data[MAX];
    char *ptr, buf[256], *ix;
    int line = 0, i, j, col = MAX;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(fp==NULL) return 1;
    printf("File is open successfully.\n");
    while((ptr = fgets(buf, 256, fp)) != NULL){
        // printf("%s", ptr);
        ix = strtok(buf, " ");
        if (ix == NULL) break;
        if ((sscanf(ix, "%d%*c", &i) != 1) || (i < line)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error line %d indicated as %d\n", line, i);
            return 1;
        }
        while (line < i) {
            for(j=0; j<col; j++) printf(" 00");
            printf("\n");
        }
        col = 0;
        while (ix = strtok(NULL, " ")) {
            if (col >= MAX) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Too much elements line %d (more than %d)\n", line, MAX);
                return 2;
            }
            if ((sscanf(ix, "%d/%x", &i, &j) != 2) || (col > i)){
                fprintf(stderr, "Incorrect syntax line %d elt %d\n", line, col);
                return 3;
            }
            while(col < i) data[col++] = 0;
            if (j == 0x99) j = 0;
            data[col++] = j;
        }
        for(j=0; j<col; j++) printf(" %02x", data[j]);
        printf("\n");
        line++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I see where it's going. Another question, how do I display the column and row? For example, 0 1 2 3 4, etc.